# Laravel 5.3 : Pages not loading properly

Tags: laravel

When the user log in or register, he is supposed to go the dashboard, but instead of it, it is being located to the /login page, which is not even there and hence error occours:

> Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.
>
> 1/1
> NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

**Routes:**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
})->name('home');

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function(){
Route::get('upload',function(){
    return view('files.upload');
});

Route::get('/wallet',[
        'uses' => 'WalletController@getwallet',
        'as' => 'wallet'
]);

Route::post('/addmoney',[
        'uses' => 'WalletController@addmoney',
        'as' => 'addmoney'
]);

Route::post('/signup',[
    'uses' => 'UserController@postSignUp',
    'as'   => 'signup'
    ]);

Route::post('/signin',[
    'uses' => 'UserController@postSignIn',
    'as'   => 'signin'
    ]);

Route::get('/dashboard',[
     'uses' => 'UserController@getDashboard',
     'as'   => 'dashboard',
     'middleware' => 'auth'
    ]);

Route::post('/handleUpload','FilesController@handleUpload');

Route::get('/pay', ['as' => 'pay', 'uses' => 'PaymentController@pay']);

# You will need one more.

Route::get('/payment/status', ['as' => 'payment_status', 'uses' => 'PaymentController@status']);

/**
 * Using Named Routs to demonstrate all the possibilities.
 */
});
```

**User controller:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use InvalidConfirmationCodeException;
use Flash;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

class UserController extends Controller

{   
public function getDashboard(){    
    return view('files.dashboard');
}

 public function postSignUp(Request $request)
 {
    $this -> validate($request,[
      'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
      'name'  => 'required|max:20',
      'password' => 'required|min:4'
      ]);

    $email = $request['email'];
    $name = $request['name'];
    $password = bcrypt($request['password']);


    $user = new User();
    $user->email =$email;
    $user->name = $name;
    $user->password = $password;


    $user->save();

    return redirect()->route('dashboard');

    //Auth::login($user);
 }

 public function postSignIn(Request $request)
 { 
    $this -> validate($request,[
        'email' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required'
        ]);

   if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request['email'], 'password' => $request['password']]))  {

        return redirect()->route('dashboard');
    }

        return redirect()->back();          
 }       
}
```

**WalletController**

```
 public function getwallet(){
    return view('files.wallet');
}



public function addmoney(Request $request){

    $this->validate($request,[
        'amount'=>'required'
        ]);

    $amount = $request['amount'];

    $wallet = new Wallet();
    $wallet->amount=$amount;

    $wallet->save();
    
    return redirect()->route('/addmoney'); 
}
```

**Even when I try localhost:8000/dashboard , it loads as localhost:8000/login as shows same error.Also, same problem occurs when I try to load /addmoney page, when the user submit amount and redirect to the next addmoney page.**

Comment: at the sign up you are only inserting the new user to database but session is not started.

Comment: It's not even working properly when I used /dashboard directly. But, How can I start the session @P_95 .

Comment: perhaps by getting the id of the inserted user and using one of the Auth-methods: `Auth::loginUsingId($user->lastInsertId());`

Comment: `/dashboard` route may be under auth middleware group and you may not have route for login. something like `Route::get('/preSignIn', 'UserController@preSignIn');` which returns the login form view.

Comment: Yes, the dashboard is under web middleware, so I think it might work if I remove it out of it? or do I have to make another function for signin under the user controller? @SanzeebAryal

Comment: Oh, okay, Thank you @P_95

Comment: I tried it, but isn't working @SanzeebAryal . Any other clue?

Comment: @Rock i dont see any get request for login form in routes. `php artisan make:auth` will provide you all authentication routes.

Comment: @SanzeebAryal okay, thank you i'll try that :)

Answer (score 0):

I see your dashboard view view is in file.controller but you use the auth middleware. Put your dashboard view in your dashboard view in the auth folder.

Default in Laravel: `resources/views/auth/yourviewhere`

Comment: put the dashboard view in the resources/views/auth and deleted it from files folder. also changed the path of it in controller function getdashboard(). But,  still isn't working. what to do now?

Comment: @Rock That's weird. Try php artisan view:clear and php artisan route:clear. Also is the dashboard the only blade here? Is it dashboard the one you cannot find? Or do you use @extends('other.view')?

Comment: No, I have other views too and I can't find two views, /dashboard and /addmoney. Whenever I try to load these two, same error occurs. I thought of solving one issue first. But yes, this error occurs wth two pages. Also, tried view and routes clear but still same problem.

Comment: I just added the controller to load /addmoney page also